# Ionic-Angular problem with ngx-translate/http-loader

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, translate

I am using ngx-translate and ngx-translate/http-loader for translating my ionic/angular project. I have this code inside app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/", ".json");
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
      return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/", ".json");
    }
```

I have this error:

**Use const or class constructors instead of named functionseslint(prefer-arrow/prefer-arrow-functions)**

I searched online but I not find a solution, what is the problem?

My configuration is:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "10.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  }
```

Comment: If you look in the documentation it seems they are wrapping the function in parentheses [here](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#aot) . Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks, I tried but the error persist

Comment: Okey, well judging by the error it seems it's some ESLint-rule that flags the error. Can you try the suggestion and make it a arrow function instead? Something like: export const createTranslateLoader  = (http: HttpClient) => new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/", ".json");